# How to identify which specific php file/function is causing the 508 Error (resources exhausted)

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring

My client getting this error out of the blue this weekend. I do maintenance on this wordpress website and it has been online for about 10 years

> **Resource Limit Is Reached**
>
> The website is temporarily unable to service
>   your request as it exceeded resource limit.
>
> ---
>
> Please try again later.
>   Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2
>   mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.4.30 Server at www.clientwebsite.com Port 80

I am trying to troubleshoot it using the `top -c` command to monitor the activity on the server and `exit();` command in my wp-config.php at various points but it's not narrowing down the scope of the issue.

If you have faced this problem at some stage and have some suggestions, I would much appreciate that.

Edit: Forgot to mention that when I am monitoring the details using `top -c', this is what I get:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                         

733791 vdog  20   0  345m  73m  12m R 100.0  0.5   1:02.26 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      
741702 vdog  20   0  250m  72m  12m R 100.0  0.5   0:27.38 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL      
746203 vdog  20   0  242m  70m  16m R 51.9  0.4   0:01.56 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL       
746182 vdog  20   0  332m  56m 7800 R 45.9  0.4   0:01.38 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL       
746204 vdog  20   0  215m  41m  15m R 27.0  0.3   0:00.81 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
```

See how httpd is taking 100% CPU usage.
It's not very helpful if I want to track down a file or function.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the log files (`/var/log/apache2/*error.log` by default, location may be overwrite by the [ErrorLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) directive)